# angular 2 get component invoking a pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to know which component that calls my pipe.

I do not want to give the component as arguments to the pipe, such as this 
`{{ "textArg" | myTranslatorPipe:thisTemplate }}`.

I want this `{{ "textArg" | myTranslatorPipe }}` and still access the component.

```
export class myTranslatorPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): string {
        //get component here ?
    }   
}
```

how will I accomplish this ?
thanks in advance !

Comment: What is your purpose? Do you want to get component name or `componentRef`?

Comment: yurzui: preferably component ref. : )

Comment: I would imagine `ComponentRef` can be injected into the pipe. It it can be injected into the component, then it should be able to be injected into the pipe. They use the same injector.

Comment: why you need `Component` inside Pipe..? pipe is just to tweak in the value based on the collection/value supplied to it...

Comment: Pankaj Parkar: because I want to give different results depending on the invoking component. I do not want to specify the component as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to do this was to directly pass the component to the pipe as a parameter.

The transform method receives an infinite number of parameters inside `args`, the following code it'll do the trick:

```
export class myTranslatorPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, componentRef: any): string {
        //component is stored inside the 'componentRef' 
        if (typeof componentRef === 'undefined' || componentRef === null) {
            throw Error('Missing "componentRef" parameter, correct implementation is "myTranslatorPipe: this".');
        }
        // here you can use your component reference
    }   
}
```

The only thing is that you'll have to implement your pipe this way `{{ "textArg" | myTranslatorPipe: this}}` instead of just `{{ "textArg" | myTranslatorPipe }}`.

The validation is not mandatory: `typeof componentRef === 'undefined' || componentRef === null`